# wordpress — Featured Images different sizes

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Anyone can help with this problem.
I want to have this function in my theme, something like this:

http://www.frogsthemes.com/wordpress-themes/foliogrid-pro

Select different sizes to the featured image in the same page?
How can I do it? Anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the size of the featured image with [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail). Example:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(120, 90) ); ?>`

The logic to switch sizes is your to make.

PS your question is vague. The link you provided does not show different sizes. I assume you mean the demo on that page.

Comment: Hello

The link it was for the theme:

http://foliogridpro.frogsthemes.com/?style=Light

In the theme they have different widths. A small, medium and large.
So I want to do something like this. 

I want to be able to choose this in the post edit.